# the getSource() and getActionCommand()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-handling, action

What is getSource? and what does it return?

and what is getActionCommand() and what does it return??

I am getting confused between these two can anyone give or differentiate them to me? what's the use of getSource and getActionCommand() in UI's? specifically TextField or JTextField?

Comment: which part exactly of the api doc don't you understand?

Comment: I have an Idea on how it works, I just need a deeper/denser information.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the [`ActionEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) class, then there is a big difference between the two methods.

**`getActionCommand()`** gives you a String representing the action command. The value is component specific; for a `JButton` you have the option to set the value with `setActionCommand(String command)` but for a `JTextField` if you don't set this, it will automatically give you the value of the text field. According to the javadoc this is for compatability with `java.awt.TextField`.

**`getSource()`** is specified by the `EventObject` class that `ActionEvent` is a child of (via `java.awt.AWTEvent`). This gives you a reference to the object that the event came from.

**Edit:**

Here is a example. There are two fields, one has an action command explicitly set, the other doesn't. Type some text into each then press enter.

```
public class Events implements ActionListener {

  private static JFrame frame; 

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    frame = new JFrame("JTextField events");
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
    field1.addActionListener(new Events());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Field with no action command set"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(field1);

    JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);
    field2.addActionListener(new Events());
    field2.setActionCommand("my action command");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Field with an action command set"));
    frame.getContentPane().add(field2);


    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(220, 150);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String cmd = evt.getActionCommand();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Command: " + cmd);
  }

}
```

Comment: let me get this Straight getActionCommand returns me the value / tha name of my TextField? that I am currently focus on? For Example I  have  a JTextField named "TextField1" the getActioncommand will return to me it's the name of that Variable? or the Message inside that TextFie;d?

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you are not explicitly setting the action command via `setActionCommand()` then `getActionCommand()` will return you the contents of the text field; i.e. whatever has been typed in there.

Answer (score 9):

[`getActionCommand()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29)

> Returns the command string associated with this action. This string allows a "modal" component to specify one of several commands, depending on its state. For example, a single button might toggle between "show details" and "hide details". The source object and the event would be the same in each case, but the command string would identify the intended action.

IMO, this is useful in case you a single command-component to fire different commands based on it's state, and using this method your handler can execute the right lines of code.

`JTextField` has [`JTextField#setActionCommand(java.lang.String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setActionCommand%28java.lang.String%29) method that you can use to set the command string used for action events generated by it.

[`getSource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29)

> Returns: The object on which the Event initially occurred.

We can use `getSource()` to identify the component and execute corresponding lines of code within an action-listener. So, we don't need to write a separate action-listener for each command-component. And since you have the reference to the component itself, you can if you need to make any changes to the component as a result of the event.

If the event was generated by the `JTextField` then the `ActionEvent#getSource()` will give you the reference to the `JTextField` instance itself.

Answer (score 1):

I use getActionCommand() to hear buttons. I apply the setActionCommand() to each button so that I can hear whenever an event is execute with event.getActionCommand("The setActionCommand() value of the button").

I use getSource() for JRadioButtons for example. I write methods that returns each JRadioButton so in my Listener Class I can specify an action each time a new JRadioButton is pressed. So for example:

```
public class SeleccionListener implements ActionListener, FocusListener {}
```

So with this I can hear button events and radioButtons events. The following are examples of how I listen each one:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getActionCommand().equals(GUISeleccion.BOTON_ACEPTAR)) {
        System.out.println("Aceptar pressed");
    }
```

In this case GUISeleccion.BOTON_ACEPTAR is a "public static final String" which is used in JButtonAceptar.setActionCommand(BOTON_ACEPTAR).

```
public void focusGained(FocusEvent focusEvent) {
    if (focusEvent.getSource().equals(guiSeleccion.getJrbDat())){
        System.out.println("Data radio button");
    }
```

In this one, I get the source of any JRadioButton that is focused when the user hits it. guiSeleccion.getJrbDat() returns the reference to the JRadioButton that is in the class GUISeleccion (this is a Frame)

Answer (score 0):

The getActionCommand() method returns an String associated with that Component set through the setActionCommand() , whereas the getSource() method returns an Object of the Object class specifying the source  of the event.