# Add a complex image in the panel, with buttons around it in one customized user interface

Tags: java, swing, icons, jbutton, layout-manager

How can i have this image like below into the `slavePanel` and on top of that JPanel adjust the `JButtons` which looks like the image but having buttons correctly wrapped around? (Right now they are shaped in 1 row, 4 column)

[image]

```
  //
  // Shot Gun mover up/down/left/right, middle on is for zoom
  //
  public void GunMover(JPanel configPanel) throws IOException {

    // Master Panel - holds everything
    JPanel masterPanel = new Panel();
    masterPanel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());

    // Slave Panel - with image background 
    JPanel slavePanel = new Panel();
    slavePanel.setLayout(new SpringLayout());

    // Row 1
    final JButton ptzLeft = new JButton("<");       
    masterPanel.add(ptzLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);

    // Row 2
    final JButton ptzRight = new JButton(">");   
    masterPanel.add(ptzRight, BorderLayout.CENTER);    

    // Row 3
    final JButton ptzUp = new JButton("^");   
    masterPanel.add(ptzUp, BorderLayout.WEST);    

    // Row 4
    final JButton ptzDown = new JButton("down");   
    masterPanel.add(ptzDown, BorderLayout.CENTER);    

    // How do i add slavePanel this background and add all the JButtons 
    // According to that image shape?

    // Layout the panel.
    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(masterPanel,
                                1, 4, //rows, cols
                                6, 6, //initX, initY
                                6, 6);        

    configPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    configPanel.add(masterPanel);   
  }
```

**Follow up:** Excellent one from `Andrew Thompson`  + at-least my broken method

[image]

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class New extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private ImageIcon errorIcon =
          (ImageIcon) UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
  private Icon infoIcon =
          UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
  private Icon warnIcon =
          UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        New t = new New();
      }
    });
  }

  public New() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel slavePanel = new NewPanel();
    slavePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 4, 4));
    add(slavePanel);    

    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
    button.setBorder(null);
    button.setFocusable(false);
    button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setIcon((errorIcon));
    button.setRolloverIcon((infoIcon));
    button.setPressedIcon(warnIcon);
    button.setDisabledIcon(warnIcon);
    slavePanel.add(button);    

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }
}


package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class NewPanel extends JPanel {

  private Image imageGui;
  private static Dimension screen;

  public NewPanel() {
    try {
      imageGui =
              ImageIO.read(
              (InputStream) NewPanel.class.getResourceAsStream(
              "/image/ptz.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

    Border border = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(11, 11, 11, 11);
    setOpaque(true);
    setBorder(border);
    setFocusable(true);
    setSize(getPreferredSize());
    revalidate();
    repaint();
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(imageGui, 0, 0,
            imageGui.getWidth(null), imageGui.getHeight(null), null);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(imageGui.getWidth(null), imageGui.getHeight(null));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Use a 3x3 `GridLayout`
2. For each of the 9 cells get a subimage:

- For every second component, add a label with the subimage.
- For every other component, add a `JButton` from which the space is removed.  Use the subimage as icon, but you'll need alternate icons to indicate focus, activation etc.  This example puts a red border around the 'pressed' icon.

[image: Compass Buttons]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class CompassButtons {

    public CompassButtons(BufferedImage bi) {
        int w = bi.getWidth();
        int h = bi.getHeight();
        int step = w / 3;
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        int count = 0;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < w; ii += step) {
            for (int jj = 0; jj < h; jj += step) {
                // This is it - GET THE SUB IMAGE
                Image icon = bi.getSubimage(jj, ii, step, step);
                if (count % 2 == 1) {
                    JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(icon));

                    // make it transparent
                    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);

                    // remove border, indicate press using different icon
                    button.setBorder(null);

                    // make a 'pressed' icon..
                    BufferedImage iconPressed = new BufferedImage(
                            step, step, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                    Graphics g = iconPressed.getGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(icon, 0, 0, p);
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g.drawRoundRect(
                            0, 0,
                            iconPressed.getWidth(p) - 1, 
                            iconPressed.getHeight(p) - 1,
                            12, 12);
                    g.dispose();
                    button.setPressedIcon(new ImageIcon(iconPressed));

                    button.setActionCommand("" + count);
                    button.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {
                        System.out.println(ae.getActionCommand());
                    });

                    p.add(button);
                } else {
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(icon));
                    p.add(label);
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        center.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        center.add(p);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, center);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNN04.png");
        final BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(url);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new CompassButtons(bi);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is so cool. May I ask what does `button.setActionCommand("" + count);` do?
Oracle java doc only explain: Sets the action command for this button. But now I have no idea what does Action command mean.....

Comment: @JianHe It is passed to the `ActionEvent` created, and can be accessed via `ActionEvent.getActionCommand()`. We could alternately use `ActionEvent.getSource()` to find the source component (like a `JButton`). But more commonly we create an `ActionListener` (or `Action` - e.g. a `saveEditsAction`) for a particular control (or controls - like both a button and menu) and then getting either the action command or the source component becomes irrelevant. I used the action command in a single action listener in that example to make the code shorter and show the button 'number' in the console.

Comment: through this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214958/the-getsource-and-getactioncommand/8215194). I got it. Thanks. Now I totally understand it.

Answer (score 3):

1) you have to prepare the Icons before and for every 5 JButtons ([event here came from ButtonModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968))

- basic Icon without Focus
- Icon for `isRollover()`
- Icon for `isPressed()`

2) [how to set Icons and to remove all "balast" from JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919280/714968)

3) put these `5 JButtons` to the `JPanel` with painted circles (RemoteSet)

Comment: *"every 5 JButtons"* 5 buttons?  I get N/S/E/W for 4 - but which is the 5th button?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson `which is the 5th button?` eeeehmmm == Enter Key in the middle in the CENTER area(Panasonics Remotes has similair design)

Comment: Thank you. Edited above, middle one is not important was hard to find up/down/left/right, which is nicely working.

Comment: @YumYumYum heheh nothing complicated, great answerers (excluding my person) in this thread, isn't it

Answer (score 3):

Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887628/230513), I got a start by changing `MoveButton` like this:

```
this.setBorderPainted(false);
```

You could give `ControlPanel` a [*Custom Layout Manager*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html). I'd also add a background image and some kind of visual feedback based on the `ButtonModel` state, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10861923/230513).